# jquery based component not getting re-rendered

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a jquery based react component ( react-simple-jstree) which is part of another react component.

When the props on the parent componet changes (refresh true is being passed), I want this jquery based component to get refreshed

```
class UserTree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var curTime = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.refresh} {/* I see this changed */}
        <b> {curTime}</b> {/* this also changes */}
        <TreeView treeData={this.props.data} /> {/* but this doesnt re-render , why ? */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But whenever new props are passed `( refresh : true)`, I see that `componentDidUpdate` is called, true is printed and the time changes
 but the `TreeView` component which is a `jstree` ( jquery based component ) is not getting rerendered

What am I missing and what could be the possible way to refresh the `TreeView` component ?

Comment: Is `this.props.data` changing too? If it doesn't, then even though the `<UserTree/>` re-renders (from 'refresh' prop change), the props being passed to `<TreeView/>` aren't changed, so it won't re-render.

Comment: In `TreeView` updating the props doesn't mean that your component will re-render. Components are re-rendered only when the state is updated/changed. Can you share the part of your TreeView component which you want to update on props change? Then only I will be able to tell you what exactly you need to do.

Comment: @NikhilThakur "Components are re-rendered only when the state is updated/changed" state OR props*